# Installing simplest plugin on German Windows XP

Tags: wix, firebreath

I'm trying to figure out why the simplest firebreath plugin wont install on a German Windows XP SP3. I'm running Windows XP as a virtual machine.

The event viewer in Windows XP tells me something about the Windows Installer aborting but not why. I'm logged in as the administrator.

The installer works on Windows 7.

For development I use Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 and some one months old firebreath trunk.

Is this is known problem? What are the typical steps I could use to track down the issue?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: did you create a log file of the installation? See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/7126077/33499

Comment: Try running setup as administrator

Comment: try installing it manually and see if it works

Comment: @Wimmel I have posted the log output here: http://pastebin.com/NDGXqc8r    I cannot see what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @taxilian: regsvr32 gives me LoadLibrary("npSimple.dll") failed. Set modul cannot be found. (translation from German) Any ideas?

Comment: @SunilAgarwal: I'm logged in as the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error saying module can't be found it means that you are missing a .dll file needed to make the plugin work.  The most common if it works on most computers (or many) but not that one is that your .dll was compiled with a dynamic runtime, in which case you'll have to install the common runtime for whatever version of visual studio you compiled it with.

For example, the runtime distributable for vs2008 is at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help you to find out which dll is missing.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. My problem was that I tried to install a plugin built in debug configuration. But Visual Studion 2010 redistributables don't install debug runtime libs...