# InstallShield 2012 error code 1925: Requires admin privileges for setup

Tags: installation, installshield

I'm trying to package and deploy a wpf application. I used install shield and I have created the setup file. When I try running the setup  file it keeps throwing this error code

> 1925: it needs admin privileges to run the setup.

How do I configure the setup file to be run by any user? Should I make any changes in the registry during the creation of setup file in install shield? Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create a per-user installation. Since Windows Vista, this requires several steps, but was made simpler with Windows 7. I would check a [verbose log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130758/89999) in case it highlights any specific problems, and if not, follow this general advice:

1. If this is always a per-user installation, set *General Information > Require Administrative Privileges* to **No** and set the [ALLUSERS property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559.aspx) to empty.

   If this is only conditionally per-user, leave them as **Yes** and **1** respectively, and use the [MSIINSTALLPERUSER property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007.aspx) with ALLUSERS=2 to select a per-user installation at run time. Note that this only works on Windows 7 (MSI 5.0) and later.
2. Ensure that your setup.exe, if you are using one, does not elevate. Set *Required Execution Level* to **Invoker** in the setup.exe tab of the Releases view.
3. If you are not using MSIINSTALLPERUSER, ensure that you are not installing any resources to any machine locations. This includes installation files to the ProgramFilesFolder, registry keys to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, or other machine-level items such as Windows Services. Note that you may have to exclude services from MSIINSTALLPERUSER scenarios as well.