# IE custom download manager (CSIEDownloadManager)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I am using the following [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSIEDownloadManager-8ab5d910) that provides an example on how to create an IE  custom download manager. The example is rather simple but when I install and run it , it does not work... I think the reason is that the it *supposed* to change the resitry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DownloadUI but I do not see it does that...

Any idea...? (Thanks)

Comment: So you did build that project, including the setup project and then ran the msi that came out of it, right?

Comment: Yes, Installation passed successfully

Comment: create a log file and check if the key is created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126077/create-an-msi-log-file

Comment: The registry key is not created from the MSI file (it is not in the setup). It is in part of the Register() method of the IEDownloadManager class (which inherits from IDownloadManager).  Maybe the method is not being called..?

Comment: Here is the Register method:   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void Register(Type t)
        {
            string ieKeyPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\";
            using (RegistryKey ieKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(ieKeyPath))
            {
                ieKey.SetValue("DownloadUI", t.GUID.ToString("B"));
            }
        }