# MSI Silent Installation not Working

Tags: windows-installer, silent-installer

I am trying to install an MSI via PowerShell using the following code:

```
msiexec /a [MSI File] /qn
```

According to the Event Log, the software was installed successfully, but does not appear in either *Add/Remove Programs* nor inside the registry key. I am on a laptop that does not have Admin control, which is why I'm using `/a` instead of `/i`. I have also tried the following code to same results as before:

```
msiexec /a [MSI File] ALLUSER=2 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0 /qn
```

Any clue as to why this is happening, and how I can fix this so the software can be properly installed?

Comment: How is this related to PowerShell? The MSI failure is not related to PowerShell.

Comment: Have the installer [log what it's doing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130758/1630171) to actually see if anything goes wrong: `/l*v "install.log"`

Answer (score 4):

The steps you are taking are not supposed to have the outcome you expect. As you briefly allude to, `/a` performs what is called an [administrative install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541). This is not an installation of the software, but instead the creation of an uncompressed installation source. This is typically intended for a company to use in order to avoid having to physically share the installation disc (back when there were installation discs).

Your second command line has several errors:

- `/a` still does not "install" the software
- `ALLUSER=2` is meaningless as the property `ALLUSER` is not defined. The correct property name would be [`ALLUSERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559). You are probably looking for `ALLUSERS=2 MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1` to invoke the Windows Installer 5 / Windows 7 or later per-user redirection. Note that [`MSIINSTALLPERUSER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007) may not work correctly unless the package was [authored with this so-called dual purpose in mind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068).
- `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0` might do the opposite of what you likely expect. Windows Installer works primarily on a defined/undefined (that is non-empty string vs. empty string) definition for truth rather than a 1/0 definition. While the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750) does say that setting it to 1 will prevent the application from being listed in ARP, the implementation likely checks for any non-empty string value. (Of course, per the first bullet it doesn't matter yet as you're not performing a normal installation.)

Your best bet is to acquire administrative privileges, in which case a simple `msiexec /i package.msi` will do the job. If you cannot acquire administrative privileges, and the package is authored appropriately, you may be able to install it with `msiexec /i package.msi ALLUSERS=2 MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`. In either case you can also pass `/qn` or similar to suppress the UI, but I would suggest avoiding that until you have things working. As mentioned in a comment, adding `/l*v verbose.log` can help diagnose what's happening no matter the level of UI.

Comment: The 2nd command worked to get me around putting in Admin credentials, but I was prompted with the following error:

Error writing to file:
C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\fortiapd.sys. Verify that you have access to that directory.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Unlikely. That appears to be (the first step of) installing a driver, which unequivocally requires administrative privileges. So this package is _not_ dual purpose. If the driver is not necessary, perhaps it can be removed with a transform, but only the vendor is likely to know the ramifications of such a change.

Comment: So it looks like I need to get the Admin credentials. If I were to get the credentials, would I be able to plug them into my installation command?