# How to write the below code In the scriptblock of invoke-command in the single line

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have to execute `myexample.msi` on the remote machine.
Below logic I have tried but the msi is executed and didn't show any error:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername -ScriptBlock {
  msiexec /i "myexample.msi" /q UserName="my username" password="my password" /log C:\karthik.txt
}
```

So any one please suggest.

Comment: Create a logfile and check that for errors/warnings. Make sure you get the [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988.aspx) [right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130758/1630171).

Comment: if the msi is executed, what error do you expect here ?

Comment: Error is not showing but msi is not installed in the computer name