# SystemFolder doesn't resolve properly

Tags: c#, windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to copy a few files into the `C:\Windows\System32` folder (and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` respectively) in a simple *WIX* setup using the `SystemFolder` variable. However, <strike>it always seems to resolve to a weird path I'm not even having the slightest idea where MSI is getting that from</strike>.

<strike>Basically, `SystemFolder` resolves to the following: `E:\SystemFolder\` (no, that's not a variable, the folder is actually called `SystemFolder`).</strike>

---

**Edit**

Alright, it seems that the variable isn't really resolved at all. I don't know where MSI is getting the `E:\` from, but as soon as I alias `$(var.WindowsSystemFolder)`, the correctly resolved variable `SystemFolder` becomes just `SystemFolder` (plain text), which isn't further processed. Help. :S

---

#### Variables.wxi (excerpt)

```
<!-- Platform Configuration -->
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
<?define WindowsSystemFolder = "System64Folder" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define WindowsSystemFolder = "SystemFolder" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

#### Product.wsx (excerpt)

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="WINSYSTEMFOLDER" Name="$(var.WindowsSystemFolder)" />
</Directory>
```

#### somewhere.wsx

```
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="WINSYSTEMFOLDER">
    <Component Id="RandomComponent" Guid="7784D238-2502-45B4-B5B3-180D31E56485">
      <File Id="RandomFile"
        Name="$(var.MyProject.TargetFileName)"
        Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" />
```

#### Flags passed to candle

```
-dDebug -dPlatform=x86 -arch x86
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `E:\SystemFolder` is coming from the combination of [`TARGETDIR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372064) (which is evaluating to the same as [`ROOTDRIVE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371372), which is in turn the drive in the system with the largest amount of free space), and the literal text SystemFolder or System64Folder. This is because the [`Name` attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directory.html) defines a path, not a reference to a predefined [system folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905#system_folder_properties).

Per [How To: Add a File To Your Installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html), you can put system folder properties in the `Id` attribute. If you want to give them an alternate Id that you can reference without the variable notation, create a directory beneath it with no Name (or possibly `Name='.'`). For instance, this modification to your Product.wsx excerpt may work (I haven't tested):

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="$(var.WindowsSystemFolder)">
    <Directory Id="WINSYSTEMFOLDER"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [run your .msi with logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126077/create-an-msi-log-file), to find out where it is actually going to.

The system folder seems... special.  In my log file it shows this:

```
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): System32Folder = C:\
```

Which of course makes no sense but that's what is happening.