# How to find UILevel settings in MSI installer

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to setup a custom Dragon Medical install to deploy to clients/customers however the /qb! command is not installing the program correctly.

If I use /qn it works with no issue however I don't want a completely silent install but the customer might run it multiple times and I want a visual representation of the install that can't be cancelled to minimize issues.

I have Orca and can edit the MSI but can't find out what's different between /qb! and /qn that makes it work at one UILevel but not at the other.

I will attach the MSI at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3clo3g4wg3psmd/Dragon%2015.msi?dl=0) and if anybody could shed some light on this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I would recommend taking a [verbose log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130758) of both `/qb!` and `/qn` installations, and look for differences (other than timestamps).

Comment: That's a good suggestion so I did that and saved the logs.
There are 34278 lines in the successful log, and 32936 lines in the unsuccessful log.
I will upload and attach the logs but I'm not sure the best way to sort through them to find the appropriate information.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dzz0xncjbdk9fxn/AACBqHkMA8eOkgwccyfUbvata?dl=0 is the link to the logfiles.

Comment: I believe that Dragon Medical Practice Edition is using a new type of license authentication since version 4.
It seems, that the "/qb!" command is shortcuting this new license method and installs Dragon with the same license behaviour as in older versions (asking for serial key).

This would probably be related to the UILevel set which is my understanding but I can't find a difference relating to that.

Comment: **`1)`** [Some comments on UILevel here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29677483/129130) (and how it can trigger different installation behavior when run silently or interactively). **`2)`** [Some ad-hoc comments on common design problems in MSI files here](https://serverfault.com/a/274630/20599) (from bullet point 5-6 or so, as of now July 2019).

Comment: Agreed, I see differences related to a CheckSerialNumber action, then different ISLockPermissionsInstall paths, different registry values, etc. related to the PROD_SERIAL_NUMBER value. But it sounds like you are not the author of this setup, and if so this whole question is likely off topic here.

Comment: Thank you both Stein and Michael, that is useful information and it will help me solve this a lot.

Where should I ask this question instead if it is off topic? It didn't seem appropriate in the other forums.