# Silent Install MS Visio Viewer is working but not the Silent Uninstall using command line

Tags: command-line, visio, silent-installer

I Tried to do the the silent install of MS Visio Viewer in my Sandbox and it Work

here is the code

```
visioviewer_4339-1001_x64_en-us.exe /quiet /norestart
```

and it work via command line.

However, when I tried the silent uninstall in the command line, the code wont work and the MS Visio wont be uninstalled.

Here is the code I Use.

```
MsiExec.exe /x visioviewer_4339-1001_x64_en-us.exe /qn
```

I hope someone could help me.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running MsiExec with logging enabled?  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126077/create-an-msi-log-file) on enabling logging and note the link to another post ("Logging Tips") in the comments.

Comment: Visioviewer is not an MSI installer. Are you sure using Msiexec is the correct tool to do the uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this:

```
MsiExec.exe /x {95160000-0052-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} /qn
```

Obvious.

Answer (score 0):

try using this command:

```
start  /wait msiexec.exe /x{95140000-0052-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} /qn /noreboot
```

I hope this will help you